# Can't compile GWT application on AWS instance (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, gwt, amazon-ec2, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error when trying to compile a **GWT application** on an AWS EC2 Instance under **AMI Linux**.

I already installed **Java** and have it in directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64`.

I also set up the enviroment variables:

```
$JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
$PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin;/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin
```

So, when I try to run the command:

> java -cp
>   "/var/lib/gwt/gwt-2.6.1/gwt-dev.jar;/var/my-project-source-folder"
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler com.mypackage.MyClass

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler

I downloaded and unziped `GWT 2.6.1` again but the files are fine. The same command is working perfectly in my Windows machine. Do you know what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrassing.

Here is the answer:

I was separating the paths with `;` (Windows) instead of `:` (Linux). BTW, who would think in separate things with `:`, you Linux guys know how to make hard the easy...

Comment: `;` is separating commands. You "Windows guys" have that strange notion of "drives", separate path segments with a backslash, and lines with a CRLF; when **everyone else** uses forward slashes and LF.